# TypeError: remove() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I'm writing code to remove a page  given its id

```
@app.route("/remove/<int:id>",methods=['POST','GET'])
@login_required
def remove(id):
    PAGE=MY_DAIRY.query.get(id)
    db.session.remove(PAGE)
    db.session.commit()
    flash("done deleting ")
    return render_template("ok.html")
```

When I pass an argument to the url by doing something like this  "localhost/remove/1" I get the following error
TypeError

```
TypeError: remove() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I really can't understand what's the problem here I've only specified one parameter and I'm passing it.

This is my requirements.txt file :

> ```
> Flask==0.12.2 ,Flask-Bootstrap==3.0.3.1, Flask-SQLAlchemy==1.0
> Flask-WTF==0.9.4 ,Jinja2==2.7.1, SQLAlchemy==0.8.4 ,WTForms==1.0.5
> Werkzeug==0.9.6, Flask-Login==0.4.0
> ```
>
> the whole traceback:

```
    File "/home/nidhal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__

    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

    File "/home/nidhal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app

    response = self.handle_exception(e)

    File "/home/nidhal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception

    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

    File "/home/nidhal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app

    response = self.full_dispatch_request()

    File "/home/nidhal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

    File "/home/nidhal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception

    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

    File "/home/nidhal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.dispatch_request()

    File "/home/nidhal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request

    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

    File "/home/nidhal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 228, in decorated_view

    return func(*args, **kwargs)

    File "/home/nidhal/Bureau/diaryy/app.py", line 144, in remove

    db.session.remove(PAGE)

    TypeError: remove() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.

To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.

You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:

    dump() shows all variables in the frame
    dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the ob
```

ject

Comment: You sure error is due to the the routing function and not due to the session remove function. Can you post the stack trace instead of one liner error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you [edit] the question to show us the *call* to this function please.  In fact, we really need a [mcve], or this question is likely to be closed as off-topic.  Can you also confirm exactly which line is provoking the error (is it the call to this function, or to `db.session.remove`?)

Comment: i think you left self in function as a arguement

Comment: no it's the call to the fucntion db.session remove works fine

Comment: what is `db`? is it pymongo that you are using?

Comment: no i'm using sqlachemy (sqlite3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is due the sqlachemy session remove function call.

> File "/home/nidhal/Bureau/diaryy/app.py", line 144, in remove
>
> ```
> db.session.remove(PAGE)
>
> TypeError: remove() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
> ```

Go through the documentation [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html)

What you want to use is may be delete/flush/close. remove does not take any arguments

Comment: thanks  i thought it was due to the route named remove